# Generating SAML IDP Metadata using OpenSaml

Tags: java, xml, spring, saml, provider

I am trying to generate a service which automatically generates SAML IDP Metadata. A user will enter the value of some fields such as IDP Hostname and Authentication period. An XML document will be returned which is the IDP metadata.
I can find no resources online or examples. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring with SAML then below link will be helpful to you.

**Documentation** : http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

**Sample project** : https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample